# Sticky scroll menu hiding when offset().bottom - 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky menu that appears when a user scrolls down 500px from the top of the view. I'd like to have it also hide when the user scrolls down to 500px from the bottom.

Thanks in advance.

```
var stickTop = $('.sidebar-stick').offset().top + 500;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickTop ) {
        $('.sidebar-stick').css({opacity: '1'});
        $('.stick-dummy').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.sidebar-stick').css({opacity: '0'});
        $('.stick-dummy').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to calculate both limits from top and bottom (not only top), and then add the bottom limit to the condition:

```
var stickTop = $('.sidebar-stick').offset().top + 500;
var stickBottom = $(document).height() - 500;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickTop && $(window).scrollTop() < stickBottom) {
        $('.sidebar-stick').css({opacity: '1'});
        $('.stick-dummy').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.sidebar-stick').css({opacity: '0'});
        $('.stick-dummy').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Depending on the effect that you want to create, you may want to take into account the window height too.